# Brain Segmentation To 3D Model

Tags: computer-vision, python

My goal is to take a dataset of Brain Tumor segmentations, use computer vision to locate and highlight the tumor in each slice, then combine each slice (almost like stacking) to make a 3D model. In this 3D model, you can see exactly where the tumor is located.

I am able to use CV to highlight tumors in individual layers, but the challenge comes in stacking. How would I go about stacking images to make 3D models. With this I would have to remove empty outside space in individual images and be able to give each image some depth.

How would I go about doing this? Is there any existing library that can do this?